# Why am I getting wrong output here?

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

```
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize){
bool repeating=true;
bool nonrepeating=false;
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<numsSize;j++){
        if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
            return repeating;
        }else{
            return nonrepeating;
        }
        
    }
 }
 return true;
 }
```

Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct.This was the question for which I was supposed to write a boolean function.Could anyone tell what changes should I do in this code to get correct output?

Comment: What should happen if `i==j`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 but the base logic seems right ..ie traversing two loops and comparing two elements of array?

Comment: The logic is not even close to being right. You return a value right after the very first comparison.

Comment: @Gerhardh so what changes should i do in this?

Comment: For a good question please also provide input data, output and expected output.

Comment: Please choose a title which will help others with the same issue, as SO is a repository for questions and answers rather than a personal help desk. Thank you

Comment: Losing the entire `else` logic (just delete it all) and using `return false;` after the loops right before the function close will get you much closer to what you want, I suspect. It still isn't completely correct, but it is closer. You may also want your outer loop limits to run `i=0; i<numsSize-1`, and your inner loop limits to run `j=i+1; j<numsSize` . That should get you very close

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 major problems:

You compare identical elements which obviously are always same:

```
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<numsSize;j++){
        if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
```

You will ultimately visit `i==1` and `j==1` and detect a false match.

Typically all pairs are visited by one of these loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
        ...
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        ...
```

Second issue is that you prematurely exit your function. You may return on first match.
But for first non-matching elements you first need to compare all other pairs.

```
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize)
{
    for (int i=0; i<numsSize; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i]==nums[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```